# Which crm is the best and low maintenance?

Tags: php, crm

I'm looking for CRM to use for an organization which generally works with members and contributions other daily routines tasks.

Ideally I would like to know what is best CRM available out there and what could be best for building a complex project(of course my requirement is small here)

I would also like to know..any steps and measures to take for extending any CRM on mobile as i want it to be mobile version as well..
I'm using PHP technology with mySQL.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks for your ideas,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question can have a lot of interpretations. But one begin point is know which technology your team or partner control. If you are talking in a complex project, you have to extend the base of a CRM System. So the technology is a key point.
If you have more confidence in .net the choice could be CRM Dynamics, if it's apex you can choose Salesforce, if it's PHP can be SugarCRM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Azevedo..sorry for not mentioning the technology. we are using php and we can customise it and extend the core of CRM.

Comment: Ok, this is a very important information. In PHP i cann't help you.